# Expressions to use in English about "for" and "to"

Tags: grammaticality, differences, prepositions

This question is about “for” and “to” in terms of destination or direction. Which is right? Are they both right? Could you give me more examples and information about the usage of for and to?

a. Is this the right bus stop **for** downtown?

b. Is this the right bus stop **to** downtown?

Answer (score -1):

In your example *for* is correct. It does not signify direction. It signifies purpose.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your post was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Can you elaborate on why you think for is correct and to is not with your research/reference? This kind of short answer is not encouraged in EL&U. Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see how it works here.